# Saving down onto a file and sorting after highest score! python games

Tags: python

UPDATE:
I added this as you said

```
class HighscoreHandler(object):

HIGHSCORE_FILE = "highscores.txt"  # define where to store highscores

def get_highscores(self, sort=True):  # return sorted by default
    with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "a+") as f:  # open the highscore file
        f.seek(0)  # rewind to the file start
        scores = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]  # read the scores as ints
        if sort:  # sort if required
            return sorted(scores)  # add reverse=True to `sorted()` for a descending sort
        return scores

def save_highscore(self, highscore):
    highscores = set(self.get_highscores(False))  # get the current highscore list
    if highscore in highscores:  # this highscore already exists
        return  # nothing to do...
    highscores.add(highscore)  # add the highscore to a set
    with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f:  # open the highscore file for writing
        f.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in highscores))  # store the scores
```

and then I put the `save_highscore`and `get_highscores` into my "code" part

```
# Display the final score.
drawBoard(mainBoard)
scores = getScoreOfBoard(mainBoard)
print('X scored %s points. O scored %s points.' % (scores['X'], scores['O']))
if scores[playerTile] > scores[computerTile]:
    print('You beat the computer by %s points! Congratulations!' % (scores[playerTile] - scores[computerTile]))
    highscore =  scores[playerTile] - scores[computerTile]
    get_highscores()
    save_highscore()
elif scores[playerTile] < scores[computerTile]:
    print('You lost. The computer beat you by %s points.' % (scores[computerTile] - scores[playerTile]))
else:
    print('The game was a tie!')

if not playAgain():
    break
```

but yet as I try to save the highscore to the file it tells me`name 'get_highscores' is not defined`

Comment: can you give an example of what are you trying to sort ?

Comment: I am only trying to sort the highscores, meaning the difference between the users points - the computers points

Comment: the higher the score, the higher up the file it goes

Comment: so why not save the scores in a list , and then sort it with the built in sort function , and at last insert it in the file  ?

Comment: yeah sure that works to, but I don't know how ...

Comment: your code is not very clear , can you provide the full class ?

Comment: Well my whole code is very long, but the only thing I need to do now is just save the difference in points when the person wins, and then save it to a file basically. shouldn't it be pretty easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two functions - one to read your scores, another to update them if needed. The simplest way is to just store a simple `set` (to weed out the duplicates) and just retrieve it when needed (and optionally sort it if you need to show the scores in a sorted manner:

```
HIGHSCORE_FILE = "highscores.txt"  # define where to store highscores

def get_highscores(sort=True):  # return sorted by default
    with open(HIGHSCORE_FILE, "a+") as f:  # open the highscore file
        f.seek(0)  # rewind to the file start
        scores = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]  # read the scores and turn them to int
        if sort:  # sort if required
            return sorted(scores)  # add reverse=True to `sorted()` for a descending sort
        return scores

def save_highscore(highscore):
    highscores = set(get_highscores(False))  # get the current highscore list
    if highscore in highscores:  # this highscore already exists
        return  # nothing to do...
    highscores.add(highscore)  # add the highscore to a set
    with open(HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f:  # open the highscore file for writing
        f.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in highscores))  # store space separated scores
```

Then you can use those two functions to your hearts content to manage your highscores as:

```
print(get_highscores())  # [], no highscores yet
save_highscore(5)  # add 5
print(get_highscores())  # [5]
save_highscore(12)  # add 12
save_highscore(6)  # add 6
save_highscore(8)  # add 8
print(get_highscores())  # [5, 6, 8, 12]
save_highscore(6)  # add 6 again
print(get_highscores())  # [5, 6, 8, 12], it doesn't save duplicate scores
```

**UPDATE** - You can easily turn these functions into class methods by simply adding a `self` attribute as their first method and, if you keep `HIGHSCORE_FILE` as a class property, by referring to it as `self.HIGHSCORE_FILE`, something like:

```
class HighscoreHandler(object):

    HIGHSCORE_FILE = "highscores.txt"  # define where to store highscores

    def get_highscores(self, sort=True):  # return sorted by default
        with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "a+") as f:  # open the highscore file
            f.seek(0)  # rewind to the file start
            scores = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]  # read the scores as ints
            if sort:  # sort if required
                return sorted(scores)  # add reverse=True to `sorted()` for a descending sort
            return scores

    def save_highscore(self, highscore):
        highscores = set(self.get_highscores(False))  # get the current highscore list
        if highscore in highscores:  # this highscore already exists
            return  # nothing to do...
        highscores.add(highscore)  # add the highscore to a set
        with open(self.HIGHSCORE_FILE, "w") as f:  # open the highscore file for writing
            f.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in highscores))  # store the scores
```

Then you can run it the same way by referring to an instance of it:

```
handler = HighscoreHandler()
print(handler.get_highscores())  # [], no highscores yet
handler.save_highscore(5)  # add 5
print(handler.get_highscores())  # [5]
handler.save_highscore(12)  # add 12
handler.save_highscore(6)  # add 6
handler.save_highscore(8)  # add 8
print(handler.get_highscores())  # [5, 6, 8, 12]
handler.save_highscore(6)  # add 6 again
print(handler.get_highscores())  # [5, 6, 8, 12], it doesn't save duplicate scores
```

Comment: there is no way to link this solution to a class object in any way?

Comment: Everything went smoothly, but when I ran the program, no highscores ended up onto the textfile!

Comment: @Pythongirl - check the update to see how to use it as a part of a class. As for why it doesn't work, as long as you provide it integers and a valid path to write I can't see why it wouldn't. The error is most likely somewhere else in your code.

Comment: okay, I understand. Just got one question, should I add the two definitions into my current code?

Comment: I have no idea what your `drawboard` is or how you structured the rest of your code - technically, as long as you can call these two functions to read/save your highscore it doesn't matter under what structure you place them. That's a matter of style and design.

Comment: @Pythongirl - why are you using a 'class' version (which you asked for apparently for no reason) if you just want to call the functions directly (as in the first version of the code)? If you want to use it as a class instance, you first need to instantiate it as shown in the second use example case (`handler = HighscoreHandler()`) and then call the methods on it (i.e. `handler.save_highscore(2)`). Otherwise don't use it as a class instance and use the first 'version' instead. Then you can just call global (to the module) functions as you do in your code.

Comment: ok, I would like to have it as a class version but I am very bad at creating objects in classes; could you please show me or give an example of how to do so?

Comment: @Pythongirl - there is an example on how to use it right bellow the code - you create an instance and then when needed you call its inner methods. Can't be simpler than that.

Comment: sorry but I have yet another question, I need to sort the values in order in the file. So just not print them out, but sort them in the file. Can you help me?

Comment: can you help me with the above question? ^

Comment: @Pythongirl - well use the same technique used to sort them on reading, but just on writing. Something as simple as `f.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in sorted(highscores)))` should be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list to save all the scores in :

```
  drawBoard(mainBoard, highscore)
  scores = getScoreOfBoard(mainBoard)
  print('X scored %s points. O scored %s points.' % (scores['X'],scores['O']))
  if scores[playerTile] > scores[computerTile]:
     print('You beat the computer by %s points! Congratulations!' %  (scores[playerTile] - scores[computerTile]))
     highscore =  scores[playerTile] - scores[computerTile]
     self.list.append(highscore)
  elif scores[playerTile] < scores[computerTile]:
     print('You lost. The computer beat you by %s points.' % (sc ores[computerTile] - scores[playerTile]))
  else:
    print('The game was a tie!')
```

in your **init** :

```
def __init__():
    self.list = []
```

Sort function :

```
def sort(self, list):
    list.sort()
    self.saveToFile(list)
```

saveToFile function:

```
def saveToFile(list):
    with open ('Highscore.txt', 'r+') as file:
       for i in list:
           file.write(i)
```

Comment: it tells me that `"this" is not defined`

Comment: Well I changed `this.list()`to `self.list()`and it still tells me that "this is not defined"

Comment: you mean `this`to `self` ?

Comment: it tells me `TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: well , i left it for you to put in your arguments . starting with __init__(self, ...)